# How to run 3 (with Thread) function on one button click?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

This is only a part of my code. When I clicked `btn_convert` or `btn_save function` (`self.convertThread.start` and `self.convert_and_save`) working. But when I clicked `btn_convert_save`, working only `self.open`. The question is, why after click on `btn_convert_save` starting not all 3 function ?

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

 def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__() ...
 def home(self):
    self.saveThread = SaveThread()
    self.convertThread = ConvertThread()
    btn_convert.clicked.connect(self.convertThread.start)
    btn_save.clicked.connect(self.saveThread.start)
    btn_convert_save.clicked.connect(self.convert_and_save) ...

 def convert_and_save(self):
    self.open()
    self.convertThread.start
    self.saveThread.start
    #self.convert()
    #self.save_file()

class SaveThread(QtCore.QThread):
 def __init__(self):
    super(SaveThread, self).__init__()

 def run(self):...

class ConvertThread(QtCore.QThread):
 def __init__(self):
    super(ConvertThread, self).__init__()

 def run(self):...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the brackets, instead of

```
self.convertThread.start
```

write

```
self.convertThread.start()
```